# Performing Segue After Sharing - Objective-C (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, segue

I have a twitter sharing view controller that opens in front of one of my view controllers. I make the twitter view like this:

```
if ([shareOption isEqual: @"Tweet"]) {

        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];


        [tweetSheet setInitialText:combined];
        [tweetSheet addImage:capturedScreen];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I have this line of code to switch to my next view controller:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"goBack" sender: self];
```

How can I call this line after the user finishes tweeting? I would also like this line to execute if the user decides to cancel their tweet.

**EDIT**

```
if ([shareOption isEqual: @"Tweet"]) {

        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:combined];
        [tweetSheet addImage:capturedScreen];
        iJustShared = @"YES";
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

    [tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"goBack" sender: self];

    }];

}
```

Comment: Did you look at the SLComposeViewController docs? There's a section called "Handling Results" and a property called "completionHandler".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have that line in your tweet controller, and if you want that segue to go back to the previous controller, you'll need to do `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion`.

But, since you're using SLComposeViewcontroller and you are not subclassing it, you must use a handler by setting its completion handler:

```
[tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    //actions!
}];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SLComposeViewController/completionHandler

Comment: Ok. Applied your advice to my code. However, pressing cancel on the tweet does not call the completion handler. Thoughts?

Comment: What did you do inside the handler?

Comment: I have edited my question to include my updated code.

Comment: The problem was the performSegueWithIdentifier, I suppose.